# How to merge large arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 7 arrays of objects . Every object contains data. I need to merge these arrays together and I do that with:

```
$arrayTotal = $array1;
$arrayTotal = array_merge($arrayTotal,$array2)
$arrayTotal = array_merge($arrayTotal,$array3)
$arrayTotal = array_merge($arrayTotal,$array4)
...
```

All was working great until I had my total array of something like 700 items (each sub-array had 100 items ). Apache stopped responding, I think because of a memory problem because of so many large arrays. I had problems on the 4th or 5th merge.

What is the best way to merge them and avoid errors?

Update:

```
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3908
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Child process is running
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:36 2012] [notice] Child 3908: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.
[Sat Sep 15 10:17:53 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
```

This is my apache error log. I did find some solutions with copying files to my system32 folder but they didnt work

Comment: The "related" bar on the side of this page makes me sad.

Comment: why not array_merge_recursive

Comment: @ Brendan Long 
I think u didnt read my problem
@FirmView
Tested and same error

Comment: I have two questions. First, are these 7 sequential calls to array_merge? And second, is there any way for this to work for you without merging the arrays?

Comment: i did fix the problem, merging was not making an error

Comment: This question shouldn't be devoted, it's very important since array_merge() function has high memory usage with large arrays. array_merge() is checking if there are duplications. Using + is the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not in array_merge but in curl that i was doing to external file . File was too big for curl as i see it and then we had memory problems, increasing memory in php.ini didnt fix the problem

Answer (score 9):

`array_merge` can take an unlimited number of arguments, so you can put them all in one function call:

```
$arrayTotal = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3...);
```

This should solve the problem, since I've used arrays with thousands of items in the past with no issues.

Comment: Also, `$arrayTotal = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrayofarrays);`

Comment: again i get same problem, tried to marge all arrays at same time
"Apache HTTP Server has stopped working"

Answer (score 2):

using + is more optimised then using array_merge

Write it like this, it is faster and use less resources, which seems you have problem with

```
$arrayTotal = $array1 + $array2 + $array3 + $array4; //add as much as you need :)
```

note:thanks to @ficuscr, from php [array_merge page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), a real important thing to watch is

> If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator

in short words, if you JUST want to append things, without caring for duplicates, use +

Comment: According to my experience there's not much difference between the two. But then again, this is only MY experience - I didn't benchmark both options...

Comment: Using array_merge does not return the same results as array + array.  "If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator".

Comment: @ficuscr you'r right, but after all we don't know the real need for the poster, he have 2 solutions to select from :), he may need just to append, or merge things in case things can be overwritten, I'll edit my answer to add this

Comment: i tested with + also , and again same problem "Apache HTTP Server has stopped working"

Comment: @gogic1fdsfs Locate and comment out "error_log =" lines in php.ini, then test again

Comment: that line was already commented out, as i see it at this point, there is no error in merging of arrays but in some curl operations that fill arrays. 
First i fill arrays with data that i get from external url, problem. After 4th time i try to fill array i get crash. And there is no problem in 5th time cos i tested with diferent order also.

Comment: try to increase memory for php script, unfortunately, any other solution I may recommend is installing php compiled from a source different than the one you are using

Comment: i found the problem :
i use curl to get data from page 
`code`
$curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $page);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
     $str = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     $raw= str_get_html($str);
`code`
and page on 4th place has just too much data on it

Answer (score 0):

In terms of peak memory usage `array_push($a, ...$b)` uses least memory in comparison to `array_merge($a, $b)` and `[...$a, ...$b]`.
Peak Memory usage comparisons:

1. `array_push($a, ...$b)` => $peakMemory = $aMemory + $bMemory;
2. `$a = array_merge($a, $b)` => $peakMemory = 2*$aMemory + $bMemory;
3. `$a = [...$a, ...$b]` => $peakMemory = 2*$aMemory + $bMemory;

Also, in case when you use **array_merge** or **ellipsis** operator, to reduce peak memory usage, make sure you assign the return value to the biggest array.